# Python collections.Counter: most_common complexity

Tags: python, time-complexity, counter, python-collections

What is the complexity of the function `most_common` provided by the `collections.Counter` object in Python?

More specifically, is `Counter` keeping some kind of sorted list while it's counting, allowing it to perform the `most_common` operation faster than `O(n)` when `n` is the number of (unique) items added to the counter? For you information, I am processing some large amount of text data trying to find the n-th most frequent tokens.

I checked the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and the [TimeComplexity article](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) on the CPython wiki but I couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

From the source code of [collections.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a8e814db96ebfeb1f58bc471edffde2176c0ae05/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L571), we see that if we don't specify a number of returned elements, `most_common` returns a sorted list of the counts. This is an `O(n log n)` algorithm.

If we use `most_common` to return `k > 1` elements, then we use [`heapq.nlargest`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a8e814db96ebfeb1f58bc471edffde2176c0ae05/Lib/heapq.py#L521). This is an `O(k) + O((n - k) log k) + O(k log k)` algorithm, which is very good for a small constant `k`, since it's essentialy linear. The `O(k)` part comes from heapifying the initial `k` counts, the second part from `n - k` calls to `heappushpop` method  and the third part from sorting the final heap of `k` elements. Since `k <= n` we can conclude that the complexity is:

> O(n log k)

If `k = 1` then it's easy to show that the complexity is:

> O(n)

Comment: Very elegant. Benchmarking confirms this:
        # L = rand_list(10000000)
        # timeit(lambda: sorted(L)[0:6], number=50)
        # 44.241248495000036
        # timeit(lambda: heapq.nsmallest(6, L), number=50)
        # 14.27249390999998

Comment: One thing to add that's not obvious is we only need a heap of size k here!

Comment: but if just return 1 elm, i found that most_common is faster than o(n), any advice? i compare it by loop a list and find the running max occ by myself vs directly use most common

Answer (score 16):

[The source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1b85f4ec45a5d63188ee3866bd55eb29fdec7fbf/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L575) shows exactly what happens:

```
def most_common(self, n=None):
    '''List the n most common elements and their counts from the most
    common to the least.  If n is None, then list all element counts.

    >>> Counter('abracadabra').most_common(3)
    [('a', 5), ('r', 2), ('b', 2)]

    '''
    # Emulate Bag.sortedByCount from Smalltalk
    if n is None:
        return sorted(self.iteritems(), key=_itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    return _heapq.nlargest(n, self.iteritems(), key=_itemgetter(1))
```

`heapq.nlargest` is defined in [heapq.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1b85f4ec45a5d63188ee3866bd55eb29fdec7fbf/Lib/heapq.py#L524)

Comment: @RomainG, no worries, either `n log n` if n is not specified or use heapq.nlargest  which is `O(n * log(k))`