# How to create a dictionary from existing list? Key Value must be the amount of repeats for that key

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to create a "most wanted letter" program which takes a string as input and output should be the most repeated letter in that string. Currently, I can't figure out how to create a dictionary (e.g. `dict.items():[("a", 2), ("b", 5)...]`).

```
def checkio(text: str) -> str:

    input_text = text
    lowercase_input = str.lower(input_text)
    x = list('')
    for i in lowercase_input:
        x.append(i)
```

Comment: As a side note, you can use the `str.lower()` function simply as `input_text.lower()`.

Comment: Nice, thank you! I'm a complete beginner (started learning last week), so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any imports, you can use a regular dictionary.

```
def checkio(text: str) -> str:
    lowercase_input = text.lower()
    x = {}
    for i in lowercase_input:
        x[i] = x.get(i, 0) + 1
    return max(x.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

key, value = checkio('asdafsasaaaa')  # ('a', 7)
```

**Explanation**

`dict.get` has an optional second parameter, which we set to `0`. This means if the key does not exist in the dictionary `x.get(i, 0)` will return `0`. `max` has an optional `key` parameter which accepts an anonymous (`lambda`) function. Since `dict.items()` returns an iterable of `(key, value)` pairs, we can calculate the maximum by looking at the `value` component (1st index).

**Performance**

This is inefficient versus `Counter` + `most_common` as [shown by @abc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52245866/9209546). Specifically, `most_common` uses `heapq` to reduce time complexity. See also [Python collections.Counter: most_common complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240807/python-collections-counter-most-common-complexity).

Comment: Fantastic, it works. However, would you mind explaining line 5 and 6? I'm still learning :)

Answer (score 2):

You may use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to do it directly.
Consider the following example.

```
from collections import Counter

s = "example"
c = Counter(s)
# Counter({'e': 2, 'x': 1, 'a': 1, 'm': 1, 'p': 1, 'l': 1})
```

You can also get the most common letter with

```
c.most_common(1) #[('e', 2)]
```

Note also that in case the input is a sentence you may want to avoid whitespace and in this case you can do something like `s = str.join("",s.split())`.

Comment: Great thank you, is it also possible to do this without importing counter? I'm doing some online Python game and it prohibits me from importing counter.

Comment: in this case just create a dict and for each letter you check if it exists as a key. If so you increase the counter, otherwise you add the key with value 1.