# How to access the count value of a Counter object in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x

**Scenario**

Given a few lines of code, I have included the line

`counts = Counter(rank for rank in ranks)`

because I want to find the highest count of a character in a string.

So I end up with the following object:

`Counter({'A': 4, 'K': 1})`

Here, the value I'm looking for is `4`, because it is the highest count. Assume the object is called `counts`, then `max(counts)` returns `'K'`, presumably because `'K' > 'A'` in unicode.

**Question**

How can I access the largest count/value, rather than the "largest" key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
max(counts.values())
```

would work?

---

From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

> A `Counter` is a `dict` subclass for counting hashable objects. It is a collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are stored as dictionary values.

So you should treat the counter as a dictionary. To take the biggest value, use `max()` on the counters `.value()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `max` as suggested by others. Note, though, that the `Counter` class provides the [`most_common(k)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method which is slightly more flexible:

```
counts.most_common(1)[0][1]
```

Its real [performance benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240807/python-collections-counter-most-common-complexity), however, will only be seen if you want more than `1` most common element.