# Find the nth most common word and count in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a undergraduate student who is new here and loves programming. I meet a problem in practice and I want to ask for help here.

Given a string an integer n, return the nth most common word and it's count, ignore capitalization.

For the word, make sure all the letters are lowercase when you return it!

Hint: The split() function and dictionaries may be useful.

Example:

Input: "apple apple apple blue BlUe call", 2

Output: The list ["blue", 2]

My code is in the following:

```
from collections import Counter
def nth_most(str_in, n):
    split_it = str_in.split(" ")
    array = []
    for word, count in Counter(split_it).most_common(n):
        list = [word, count]
        array.append(count)
        array.sort()
        if len(array) - n <= len(array) - 1:
            c = array[len(array) - n]
            return [word, c]
```

The test result is like in the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/grade/run/test.py", line 10, in test_one
    self.assertEqual(nth_most('apple apple apple blue blue call', 3), ['call', 1])
  File "/grade/run/bin/nth_most.py", line 10, in nth_most
    c = array[len(array) - n]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

As well as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/grade/run/test.py", line 20, in test_negative
    self.assertEqual(nth_most('awe Awe AWE BLUE BLUE call', 1), ['awe', 3])
AssertionError: Lists differ: ['BLUE', 2] != ['awe', 3]

First differing element 0:
'BLUE'
'awe'
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: why not `['apple',3]` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, the question is about finding the nth most common word. For the test case mentioned in the question, n=2, and blue occurs twice, hence is the output.

Comment: @Larry Chen, you may mark an answer that helped you solve your porblem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `Counter`, just use it wisely:

```
import collections

def nth_most(str_in, n):
    c = sorted(collections.Counter(w.lower() for w in str_in.split()).items(),key = lambda x:x[1])
    return(list(c[-n])) # convert to list as it seems to be the expected output

print(nth_most("apple apple apple blue BlUe call",2))
```

Build the word frequency dictionary, sort items according to values (2nd element of the tuple) and pick the nth last element.

This prints `['blue', 2]`.

What if there are 2 words with same frequency (tie) in first or second position ? This solution doesn't work. Instead, sort the number of occurrences, extract the nth most common occurrence, and run through the counter dict again to extract matches.

```
def nth_most(str_in, n):
    c = collections.Counter(w.lower() for w in str_in.split())
    nth_occs = sorted(c.values())[-n]
    return [[k,v] for k,v in c.items() if v==nth_occs]

print(nth_most("apple apple apple call blue BlUe call woot",2))
```

this time it prints:

```
[['call', 2], ['blue', 2]]
```

Comment: is there any performance benefit by using `c.most_common()` instead of `sorted`

Comment: `most_common` probably does the same thing, but it doesn't output the required answer so needs some post-processing to filter out the elements, specially if there are ties

Answer (score 3):

Counter return most commune elements in order so you can do like:

```
list(Counter(str_in.lower().split()).most_common(n)[-1]) # n is nth most common word
```

Comment: Why not `Counter(s.lower().split()).most_common()[n-1]` ? Also `from collections import Counter`.

Comment: if you use most_common()[n-1] you will use an O(nlogn) algorithm , if you use most_common(k) you will use O(nlogk) algorithm (check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240807/python-collections-counter-most-common-complexity))

Comment: as a good practice in python,  do not reinvent the wheel, specially when it comes to python standard library

Answer (score 2):

```
def nth_common(lowered_words, check):
    m = []
    for i in lowered_words:
        m.append((i, lowered_words.count(i)))
    for i in set(m):
        # print(i)
        if i[1] == check: # check if the first index value (occurrance) of tuple == check
            print(i, "found")
    del m[:] # deleting list for using it again


words = ['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'blue', 'BLue', 'call', 'cAlL']
lowered_words = [x.lower() for x in words]   # ignoring the uppercase
check = 2   # the check

nth_common(lowered_words, check)
```

OUTPUT:

```
('blue', 2) found
('call', 2) found
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/grade/run/test.py", line 10, in test_one
    self.assertEqual(nth_most('apple apple apple blue blue call', 3), ['call', 1])
  File "/grade/run/bin/nth_most.py", line 10, in nth_most
    c = array[len(array) - n]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

to solve this list out of index error, just put

```
maxN = 1000 #change according to your max length
array = [ 0 for _ in range( maxN ) ]
```

Comment: just `array = [0] * maxN`

Answer (score 0):

Even you can get without Collection module:
paragraph='Nory was a Catholic because her mother was a Catholic, and Nory’s mother was a Catholic because her father was a Catholic, and her father was a Catholic because his mother was a Catholic, or had been'

```
def nth_common(n,p):
    words=re.split('\W+',p.lower())
    word_count={}
    counter=0
    for i in words:
        if i in word_count:
            word_count[i]+=1
        else:
            word_count[i]=1

    sorted_count = sorted(word_count.items(), key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)         

    return sorted_count[n-1]
nth_common(3,paragraph)
```

output will be ('catholic', 6)

sorted(based on count) word count output:
[('was', 6), ('a', 6), ('catholic', 6), ('because', 3), ('her', 3), ('mother', 3), ('nory', 2), ('and', 2), ('father', 2), ('s', 1), ('his', 1), ('or', 1), ('had', 1), ('been', 1)]

Comment: This would return `('catholic', 3)` which is incorrect since the word `catholic` came 6 times. The correct output should have been `('mother', 3)`

Comment: split has taken on space and other catholic are having , with them that's why it considered them as separate word, replace p.lower.split() with re.split('\W+',p.lower()) then catholic will have count as 6 since in this example there are three top words which has count 6 to it takes one of them