# if i have a list of characters, how would i return its most two frequencies with the less time complexity?

Tags: python, list, algorithm, time-complexity, character

I'm using python language.
The clear algorithm will be enough for me.

**I've tried** using a dictionary, and counting the existence of each character if it is not in the list.
But I'm not sure if it has the possible less complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Use the in built Counter(list).most_common(n) method, as below.

```
from collections import Counter

input_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 5, 7, 3, 1]

most_common_values = [value[0] for value in Counter(input_list).most_common(2)]

print(most_common_values)
```

This outputs: `[1, 2]`.

The advantages to this approach are that it is fast, simple, and returns a list of the items **in order**. In addition, if their is a 'tie' in value count, it will return the example that appears first, as displayed in the example above.

Comment: Please refer to this question for the time complexity of the `most_common(n)` method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240807/python-collections-counter-most-common-complexity

Answer (score -1):

Use [built-int Counter in collection library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: will it make the algorithm more efficient? what will be the complexity?