# why these algorithms differ in their execution time?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

for the problem on leetcode 'Top K Frequent Elements' https://leetcode.com/problems/top-k-frequent-elements/submissions/

there is a solution that completes the task in just 88 ms, mine completes the tasks in 124 ms, I see it as a large difference.

I tried to understand why buy docs don't provide the way the function I use is implemented which is most_common(), if I want to dig a lot in details like that, such that I can write algorithms that run so fast in the future what should I read(specific books? or any other resource?).

my code (124 ms)

```
def topKFrequent(self, nums, k):
        if k ==len(nums):
            return nums
        c=Counter(nums)
        return [ t[0] for t in c.most_common(k) ]
```

other (88 ms) (better in time)

```
def topKFrequent(self, nums, k):
        if k == len(nums):
            return nums
        count = Counter(nums)   
        return heapq.nlargest(k, count.keys(), key=count.get)
```

both are nearly taking same amount of memory, so no difference here.

Comment: Well since Python is open source, so you can just look at how `nlargest` is implemented. I did the legwork for you though and found it, does it help? https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb3e0c240bc60fe08d332ff5955d54197f79751c/Lib/heapq.py#L521

Comment: The difference is probably just due to the way the result list is constructed. `heapq.nlargest` probably allocates a list of `n` elements all at once, while your list comprehension grows it incrementally.

Comment: Why do you want it to return `nums` when `k == len(nums)`? Surely, the highest k can be is the length of the list of all unique values. I.e. `set(nums)`.

Comment: In my tests with k=500, there is no noticeable difference between the execution time of `count = Counter(nums)` and both of these functions.  I.e. >99% of execution time is used by `Counter(nums)`. What values are you using for `nums` and `k`?

Comment: How often did you submit each, and what were the individual times?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode is that question for me or the OP? For my tests, see my numpy answer below. OP did not respond to my request for example values for nums and k.

Comment: @Bill The OP, otherwise I would've @'ed you. Just want to make sure they didn't just submit each only once and are acting as if LeetCode's timing were stable rather than pretty random.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240807/python-collections-counter-most-common-complexity) of `most_common`
also uses `heapq.nlargest`, but it calls it with `count.items()` instead of `count.keys()`. This will make it a tiny bit slower, and also requires the overhead of creating a new list, in order to extract the `[0]` value from each element in the list returned by `most_common()`.

The `heapq.nlargest` version just avoids this extra overhead, and passes `count.keys()` as second argument, and therefore it doesn't need to iterate that result again to extract pieces into a new list.

Answer (score 0):

@trincot seems to have answered the question but if anyone is looking for a faster way to do this then use Numpy, provided `nums` can be stored as a np.array:

```
def topKFrequent_numpy(nums, k):
    unique, counts = np.unique(nums, return_counts=True)
    return unique[np.argsort(-counts)[:k]]
```

One speed test

```
nums_array = np.random.randint(1000, size=1000000)
nums_list = list(nums_array)

%timeit topKFrequent_Counter(nums_list, 500)
# 116 ms ± 4.18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit topKFrequent_heapq(nums_list, 500)
# 117 ms ± 3.35 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit topKFrequent_numpy(nums_array, 500)
# 39.2 ms ± 185 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

(Speeds may be dramatically different for other input values)

Comment: I was curious so I submitted that six times, got accepted in 148, 345, 290, 152, 330 and 156 ms.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode sorry I don't know what you mean by 'submitted that' and 'got accepted'.

Comment: I mean at LeetCode (as that's the context of the question).

Comment: Ah, thanks, I missed the context. My code was not intended for submission to LeetCode.  Maybe `nums` is a list in LeetCode?

Comment: Yes, it's a list of ints there, not good for numpy. Still interesting to see this, though.